# React API returns empty

Tags: reactjs

fairly new to react but I have the following API data I want to create as a list or whatever:

https://jsonblob.com/53c7f296-d79d-11e8-839a-a312b719c60a

My react component looks like this:

```
class Contacts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     contacts:[]
   }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   fetch('https://api.billysbilling.com/v2/contacts?organizationId=kZeGqbBRSXyeeDoWNkF3jQ',{
     headers: {
         'X-Access-Token': API_KEY,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
   })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then(d => {
      this.setState({ contacts: d });
      console.log("state", this.state.contacts)
    })
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        this.state.contacts.map(((contact, index) =>
          <th key={`${contact.contact}${index}`}>
            <div>
              <div>
                {contact.contact}

              </div>
            </div>
          </th>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

But however it seems to return nothing. 
The console.log actually shows the data, so I am pretty stuck. 
It would be awesome if some of you could help.

The state also just returns an empty array in the react tools in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `then(response => console.log(response))`, you are not returning anything, so `d` will be `undefined` in the function given to the following `then`.

You could write it like this instead:

```js
fetch('https://api.billysbilling.com/v2/contacts?organizationId=kZeGqbBRSXyeeDoWNkF3jQ',{
  headers: {
    'X-Access-Token': API_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
})
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(d => {
  console.log(d);
  this.setState({ contacts: d.contacts });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But now it seems it cant map the data: TypeError: this.state.contacts.map is not a function

Comment: @PatrickZiebellThøgersen Judging by the data in the jsonblob, maybe it should be `this.setState({ contacts: d.contacts });` instead?

Comment: Can I bother you with one more @Tholle?

Comment: @PatrickZiebellThøgersen Consider creating a new question as it's not good practice to change a question when it has been answered.