# React with TypeScript - map an array of promises returned inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a for loop which calls a few times to database API. These calls return data for a menu, but when I try to map array I can't do it because array is empty.

First scenario:

```
const { context, orders } = props
let Data:any = []
for (let i=0; i < orders.length; i++) {
  context.webAPI.retrieveRecord("entity", orders[i].id, "?$select=colum").then(
    (result:any) => {
      const obj:any = {
        name: result.column.name
      }
      Data.push(obj)
    }
  )
}

return (
<>
  {Data.map((item:any, idx:any) => (
    <div>
      <ProgressBar key={idx} name={item.name} />
    </div>
  ))}
</>
)
```

I realize this is because API is async behaviour, but when I have tried to work with promise, I get new problems with map... I can't map a promise.

Second scenario:

```
async function getData(context:any, orders:any) {
  for (let i=0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    context.webAPI.retrieveRecord("entity", orders[i].id, "?$select=colum").then(
      (result:any) => {
        const obj:any = {
          name: result.column.name
        }
        Data.push(obj)
      }
    )
  }
  return Data
}

let Data:any = async () => getData(context, orders)

return (
<>
  {Data.map((item:any, idx:any) => (
    <div>
      <ProgressBar key={idx} name={item.name} />
    </div>
  ))}
</>
)
```

How can I map my Data array?

Comment: When the API returns the data, you need to set that data in your state so that react knows to re-render.

Comment: Yes, in the first scenario data is empty when map is executed (because webAPI is asyncrhonous) and in the second scenario I get a typescript error: " The propierty 'map' does not exists in the type '() => Promise<any>' "

Comment: Api returns the data in json format. Store that data in a state. Then map that array.

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972285/react-api-returns-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely don't want to call getData on every render, so you should store the response somewhere, it might be in the component state:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const YourReactComponent = () => {
  const [Data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function getData(context, orders) {
    for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      context.webAPI
        .retrieveRecord("entity", orders[i].id, "?$select=colum")
        .then((result) => {
          const obj = {
            name: result.column.name,
          };
          setData((prevData) => [...prevData, obj]);
        });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(context, orders);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {/* if your compiler doesn't support conditional chaining, try using Data && Data.map... */}
      {Data?.map((item, idx) => (
        <div>
          <ProgressBar key={idx} name={item.name} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Grabbing all the results and using `Promise.all` to set the state once rather than on each call would be more efficient.

Comment: That's correct, but that assumes that all the calls will be successful. If one of them fails, the whole `Promise.all` would also fail. It depends on the use-case of every system.